# Issue exporting stored variables to other components. Export returning undefined

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

Having an issue exporting stored variables to other components. Export returning undefined.

`index.svelte`

```
<script context="module">
    export const load = async ({fetch}) => {
        const res = await fetch('/queries.json')
        if (res.ok) {
            const obj = await res.json()
            return {
                props: {obj}
            }
        }
    } 
</script>

<script>
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";
    
    export let obj;   
    export const objData = writable(obj.token.token.metadata);

</script>
```

`Attributes.svelte`

```
  import { objData } from "./index.svelte"
  console.log($objData) //returns undefined

</script>
```

Comment: You should not be able to import a variable from a component in any case, the compiler should throw an error. (The exception being exports from `context=module`.)

Comment: Oh I see, the export should be in the ``<script context="module">`` tags

Comment: Not necessarily, What you are trying to do probably does not work like this. `obj` is a property of the instance (there is no point in trying to put it in the module context if it depends on a component instance), but you try to get that globally from somewhere else. You should probably look at contexts (`setContext`/`getContext`) if the components form a hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not a good practice to have stores in your components, instead create the store in a separate file, say `src/stores/object.js` and import them into your components.

As the commenter H.B. noted, you should not (be able to) import variables between components. If you feel the need to do this, it likely means you need to put these variables somewhere else and import them into the components that need them.